# Find and Verify the General Solution to an ODE Using Variation of Parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given the question:

Using y1 and y2 from part (a), use variation of parameters to find the general solution to
$$2t^2y''-5ty'+3y = \frac{5t^3}{1+t^{5/2}}, t>0$$
For full marks, you must check that you have found the solution.

Here $y_1=t^3$ and $y_2=t^{1/2}$. If V.o.P states that $y=u_1y_1+u_2y_2$, I came out with values of $$u_1=ln(t^{5/2})-ln(t^{5/2}+1) +C_1$$ and $$u_2=ln(t^{5/2}+1) +C_2$$ which gives a general solution of 
$$t^3[ln(t^{5/2})-ln(t^{5/2}+1) +C_1]+t^{1/2}[ln(t^{5/2}+1) +C_2]$$
Is this correct? And if so, how would I go about 'checking I have found the solution'?

Comment: @Isham could you tell me which WA widget you put it into so that I can see what the differences are please?
Thanks

Comment: May be, they just ask to compute the first and second derivatives of the solution, to replace in lhs of the differential equation, to simplify and to compare to the given rhs.